# Search and Replace ?___SID=U in Google Analytics

Tags: magento, google-analytics

Am looking for a solution to search and replace ?___SID=U to nothing in Google Analytics?

Anyone come up against this? The addition of the ?___SID=U is adding double the amount of pages in reports etc.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

In Google Analytics, click the "Admin" link in the sidebar

[image]

Under View, click "View Settings"

[image]

and add your query parameter by typing `___SID` into the box

[image]